# Django: Integrity error when signing up to create a new user with a custom form

Tags: python, django

I have made custom forms for log in and registration in Django using HTML/CSS and not Django's `form.as_p`.  I have the following code in views.py:

```
def login_user(request):
logout(request)
if request.POST:
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/mainpage/')
    else:
        login_message = "Your username or password is incorrect."
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'login_message': login_message})
return render(request, 'index.html')

def sign_up(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password_confirm = request.POST['password-confirm']
        if(valid_form(username, email, password, password_confirm)):
            #create the new user
            user = CustomUser(name=username, email=email, password=password)
            user.save()
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/mainpage/')
        else:
            message = "There was a problem."
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'message': message})
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

I have the following model for CustomUser in models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, null=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

My code is working for the sign up and I can create a new user after inputting the username, email and password. However, when I try to sign up again and create another user I am getting the following error:

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: UNIQUE constraint failed: Reviews_customuser.username
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error or how to resolve it. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
You are extending your customuser class with 'AbstractUser' class. In this scenario, you can add columns to the auth_user table in the database.

If you want to create all the new columns for your 'auth_user' table. you can extends your customuser class with 'AbstractBaseUser' class.

"Exception Value: UNIQUE constraint failed: Reviews_customuser.username". You are getting this error because you trying to create the same user again
```

Comment: Is there a way to resolve this issue without extending the CustomUser class with AbstractBaseUser?